# which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ will form a topology?

Tags: general-topology

which of the following subsets  of $\mathbb{R}$  will form a topology ?

$1.$ $T_1$ consists of $ \mathbb{R},\emptyset$ and every interval $[-r,r)$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}^+ $

$2.$$T_2$ consists of $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset$, and every interval $[−r, r]$, for $r$ any positive rational number

My attempt : I thinks both $T_1$ and $T_2$  will form Topology  because $T_1$ is lower limit Topology and $T_2$  will  also form topology since  any intersection of any two sets is closed in $T_2$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The first is not the lower limit topology.
Yes, prove it is a topology.
Show that it is not a Hausdorff space.

The second is not a topology.
Why is it not a topology?

Comment: Are you sure the first one is a topology? What about $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_{>0}}[-(1-\frac{1}{n}),1-\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Im not getting the 2nd one pliz elaborate more @William elliot